# How can I instantly stop a CSS animation on hover?

Tags: css

I did a CSS animation consisting of fading an element in and out.
I set up a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/BX78D/ (webkit only)

```
@-webkit-keyframes blink {
    0% {opacity:1;}
    50% {opacity:0;}
    100% {opacity:1;}
}
```

That part was fine, but here's the part I need help with:
When a user hovers over that element, I need the animation to stop and the element to be instantly set back to 100% opacity (with a new background color).  Right now, I can only get it to change the background color while continuing the current opacity animation.  Does anyone know how to do this?

The solution must be a CSS-only solution.  I can't use JS for this due to client rules.  If it can't be done with CSS only, I will have to scrap the whole effect.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/BX78D/1/

Comment: yeah, that's what I was missing!  Thanks.  (if you want to put it as an answer, I'll give you the points.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you are animating `opactiy`, you need to set it back to 100% or 1 when hovering over the element and make sure the `@keyframes` isn't running.

```
.blink:hover {
    background:red; 
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-animation-name: none;
    /* should be set to 100% opacity as soon as the mouse enters the box; when the mouse exits the box, the original animation should resume. */
}
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BX78D/1/)**

Answer (score 1):

Just override the `-webkit-animation-name` to `none`

inside the `:hover` css part write:

```
-webkit-animation-name: none;
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/BX78D/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following jQuery snippet should do the trick:

```
$(".blink").hover(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
      $(this).css('opacity', '1');
      $(this).css('background', 'red');
      $(this).css("-webkit-animation", "none");
      $(this).css("-moz-animation", "none");
      $(this).css("-ms-animation", "none");
      $(this).css("-o-animation", "none");
      $(this).css("animation", "none");
  }
});
```

The above code could be re-written as:

```
$(".blink").hover(function(){
  if ($(this).is(':animated')) {
      $(this).css({
          'opacity' : '1',
          'background' : 'red',
          '-webkit-animation' : 'none',
          '-moz-animation' : 'none',
          '-ms-animation' : 'none',
          '-o-animation' : 'none',
          'animation' : 'none'
      });
  }
});
```